# Using ForeignKey to sort with order_by and distinct not working

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm trying to sort model `Game` by each `title` and most recent `update`(post) without returning duplicates.

**views.py**

```
'recent_games': Game.objects.all().order_by('title', '-update__date_published').distinct('title')[:5],
```

The distinct method on the query works perfectly however the  `update__date_published` doesn't seem to be working.

**models.py**

*Model - Game*

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='game_covers')
    cover_display = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='game_displays')
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    reddit = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

*Model - Update*

```
class Update(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,)  # If user is deleted keep all updates by said user
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Use format: Release Notes for MM/DD/YYYY")
    content = models.TextField(help_text="Try to stick with a central theme for your game. Bullet points is the preferred method of posting updates.")
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=timezone.now, help_text="Use date of update not current time")
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article_image = models.ImageField(default='/media/default.png', upload_to='article_pics', help_text="")
    platform = ChainedManyToManyField(
        Platform,
        horizontal=True,
        chained_field="game",
        chained_model_field="game",
        help_text="You must select a game first to autopopulate this field. You can select multiple platforms using Ctrl & Select (PC) or ⌘ & Select (Mac).")
```

Comment: Do YOu need a distinct title from `Game` or article_title from `Update`?

Comment: Yeah it confusing but I need a distinct title from `Game`

Comment: which database are you using

Comment: I am using Postgresql

Comment: @ElasticPanda I am confused with this line - `The distinct method on the query works perfectly however the update__date_published doesn't seem to be working.` But your title says - `Using ForeignKey to sort with order_by and distinct not working`

Comment: I am trying to sort the Game model by the Update models date_published. There are many updates for each Game. I'm using the distinct method so that no duplicates return. However I also need to sort by the date_published for the most recent update for each game. The -update__date_published does not seem to be working as the Games are only returning in alphabetical order.

Comment: @ElasticPanda did that solved - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176151/using-foreignkey-to-sort-with-order-by-and-distinct-not-working/55177667#55177667

Answer (score 0):

See this for `distinct` reference [Examples (those after the first will only work on PostgreSQL)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

See this one for Reverse Query - [See this one for  - `update__date_published`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Example -

```
Entry.objects.order_by('blog__name', 'mod_date').distinct('blog__name', 'mod_date')
```

Your Query-

```
Game.objects.order_by('title', '-update__date_published').distinct('title')[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> The -update__date_published does not seem to be working as the Games are only returning in alphabetical order.

The reason is that the first `order_by` field is `title`; the secondary order field `-update__date_published` would only kick in if you had several identical `title`s, which you don't because of `distinct()`.

If you want the `Game` objects to be ordered by latest update rather their title, omitting `title` from the ordering seems the obvious solution until you get a `ProgrammingError` that `DISTINCT ON field` requires `field` at the start of the `ORDER BY` clause.

The real solution to sorting games by latest update is:

```
games = (Game.objects
    .annotate(max_date=Max('update__date_published'))
    .order_by('-update__date_published'))[:5]
```

Answer (score -1):

The most probable misunderstanding here is the join in your orm query. They ussually lazy-loading, so the `date_published` field is not yet available, yet you are trying to sort against it. You need the `select_related` method to load the fk relation as a join.

`'recent_games': Game.objects.select_related('update').all().order_by('title', '-update__date_published').distinct('title')[:5]`

Comment: This what I get using your code:
`FieldError at /
Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'update'. Choices are: (none)`

Comment: `'recent_games': Game.objects.prefetch_related('game_set').all().order_by('title', '-update__date_published').distinct('title')[:5]` since its a reverse selection.

Comment: Returns this:
`Cannot find 'game_set' on Game object, 'game_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`

Comment: If you specify a field in `order_by`, the ORM automatically includes it in the query without any further action on your part.

Comment: whats the error on your initial implementation? ```'recent_games': Game.objects.all().order_by('title', '-update__date_published').distinct('title')[:5]```